# Filter dropdown list options server-side asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two "large" tables in my database. These two tables hold a large set of states and countries.

**Issue and Request**

I have two dropdown list controllers inside an update panel and I'm trying to repopulate the states dropdown list everytime the user changes the country in the countries dropdown in a Partial Page PostBack. I'm currently getting an error when I change the country in the country dropdown:

**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.**

I'm not sure why it is giving me this error but all input is helpful. I have a solution that is giving me the desired results but its being done in JS and on client-side. I would like to handle this server-side instead.

Below is a shortened exerpt of the countries and states tables along with my current code with code-behind.

I also made a quick function that will create the states DataTable.(If this helps)

**Form.ascx**

```asp
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlAddressSelect" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <!-- State -->
    <div class="fieldGroup">
      <p class="inputLabel b f4"><span class="required-label"></span>State/Province:</p>
      <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlState" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="inputField" autocomplete="new-state" />
    </div>

    <!-- Country -->
    <div class="fieldGroup">
      <p class="inputLabel b f4"><span class="required-label"></span>Country:</p>
      <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="inputField" autocomplete="new-country" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlCountry_SelectedValueChanged" />
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Form.ascx.vb (Code Behind)**

```vb
Public Function GetTable() As DataTable
  Dim table As New DataTable
      With table
          With.Columns
            .Add("value", GetType(String))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
          End With
          With.Rows
            .Add("220-220", "Kaliro")
            .Add("220-221", "Manafwa")
            .Add("220-222", "Namutumba")
        .Add("22-05", "Vidin")
        .Add("22-06", "Vratsa")
            .Add("22-07", "Gabrovo")    
        .Add("222-AK", "Alaska")
            .Add("222-AL", "Alabama")
          .Add("222-AR", "Arkansas")
        .Add("223-AR", "Artigas")
        .Add("223-CA", "Canelones")
        .Add("223-DU", "Durazno")
      End With
    End With
  Return table
End Function

Public Property CountryCode As String = "-1"
ReadOnly DefaultOption As ListItem = New ListItem("--Select--", "-1")

Protected Sub DdlCountry_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Save the selected country code to the public property
    CountryCode = ddlCountry.SelectedValue       

    'Populate States
    'Dim StatesSQL As String = "..spGetAllStatesForSearch",
    '  StatesTable As DataTable = DataAction.GetDataTable(StatesSQL)
    ' The above will pull the DataTable from the Database but for this
    ' example. I provided a function that creates the table specifically
    ' for the states. The country is not needed in this as this value can
    ' be manually set for this example.

    Dim StatesTable As DataTable = GetTable()


    Dim FilteredStates As List(Of DataRow) = (From state In StatesTable.AsEnumerable Select state Where state.Field(Of String)("value").StartsWith(CountryCode & "-")).ToList

    'Clear the options from the dropdown list first before binding
    ddlState.Items.Clear()
    ddlState.DataSource = FilteredStates
    ddlState.Items.Add(DefaultOption)
    ddlState.DataTextField = "Name"
    ddlState.DataValueField = "value"
    ddlState.DataBind()

    ' The database has the first row as an empty value,
    ' So I replace this with the custom option 'DefaultOption' that I defined above
    ddlState.Items.RemoveAt(1)


End Sub
```

For the purpose of this example I'm limiting the entries in each table below. As they have over 3K entries combined and doesn't really add that much value to the problem aside from the table structure.

**Countries Table**

```
| (String) | (String)      |
| id       | country       |
----------------------------
| 222      | United States |
| 22       | Bulgaria      |
| 220      | Uganda        |
| 223      | Uruguay       |
----------------------------
```

**States Table**

```
| (String)  | (String)   |
| value     | Name       |
--------------------------
| 220-220   | Kaliro     |
| 220-221   | Manafwa    |
| 220-222   | Namutumba  |
| 22-05     | Vidin      |
| 22-06     | Vratsa     |
| 22-07     | Gabrovo    |
| 222-AK    | Alaska     |
| 222-AL    | Alabama    |
| 222-AR    | Arkansas   |
| 223-AR    | Artigas    |
| 223-CA    | Canelones  |
| 223-DU    | Durazno    |
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about my question and started to run through the methods available to me and I saw `CopyToDataTable` which is a method of the DataTableExtensions Class. So I changed:

**Original**

```
Dim FilteredStates As List(Of DataRow) = (From state In StatesTable.AsEnumerable Select state Where state.Field(Of String)("value").StartsWith(CountryCode & "-")).ToList
```

To

**Updated**

```
Dim FilteredStates As DataTable = (From state In StatesTable.AsEnumerable Select state Where state.Field(Of String)("value").StartsWith(CountryCode & "-")).CopyToDataTable
```

And this gave me the result I wanted.